# tengo este código y no se por que el else se ejecuta a la vez que el if

Tags: javascript

este código simula un bingo, cuando el numero generado aleatoria-mente coincide con el del tablero se ejecuta el if y el numero cambia por una x, todo va bien menos por que cuando encuentra el numero también salta el else,el else solo deberia ejecutarse cuando no coincide el numero aleatorio con el del tablero. No logro ver por que, tambien me gustaria generar numeros aleatorios dentro del bingocard en vez de introducirlos manualmente.

```
let bingoCard = [

{ number: 100, matched: false },

{ number: 50, matched: false },

{ number: 25, matched: false },

{ number: 10, matched: false },

{ number: 4, matched: false },
];

const nombreJugador = () => {
    let nombre;
    nombre = prompt("Bienvenido al Bingo Skyonline, cual es su nombre ");
    if (nombre !== null) {
        console.log('Bienvenido: ' + nombre)
        console.table(bingoCard);
    } else {
        window.alert('Introduzca nombre para continuar ')
    }
}

nombreJugador();


let randomNumber = () => {
    let num1 = 1;
    let num2 = 100;
    let numberRandom;
    let seguir;
    do {

        seguir = confirm('Desea pasar al siguiente turno?')
        if (seguir == true) {
            numberRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2);
            for (let i = 0; i < bingoCard.length; i++) {
                if (bingoCard[i].number === numberRandom) {
                    bingoCard[i].matched = true;
                    bingoCard[i].number = 'x';
                    console.log("Se ha encontrado el numero: " + numberRandom);
                    console.table(bingoCard);

                 } else {
                     console.log('El numero: ' + numberRandom + ' no hay coincidencias');

                }
                
           
            }
        }

    } while (seguir == true);
};

randomNumber();
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿A qué  `else` te refieres?

Comment: `= "null"` te refieres a que venga vacio??

Comment: Perdon me e equivocado, el else en realidad es el if debajo del else que esta comentado, lo cambie para ver si asi funcionaba mejor

Answer (score 0):

Esto es incorrecto:

```
if (nombre !== "null") {
```

La validaciòn para validar si `prompt()` no obtiene un valor debe ser:

```
if (nombre !== null) {
```

esto sucede cuando das clic al botòn "Cancel" o simplemente das "escape" para tratar de salir, en este caso la funciòn `prompt()` obtiene un valor `null`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que entraba al bloque else por que era un ciclo for, si el primer elemento coicidia el te imprimia que acertaste, pero para el segundo item no acertabas y ese era el problema, entonces agregue los mensajes al final del ciclo for, puse un break para que cuando encuentre un valor correcto ya no compare los demas.

Intenta de esta manera:

```
let bingoCard = [

{ number: 100, matched: false },

{ number: 50, matched: false },

{ number: 25, matched: false },

{ number: 10, matched: false },

{ number: 4, matched: false },
];

const nombreJugador = () => {
    let nombre;
    nombre = prompt("Bienvenido al Bingo Skyonline, cual es su nombre ");
    if (nombre !== null) {
        console.log('Bienvenido: ' + nombre)
        console.table(bingoCard);
    } else {
        window.alert('Introduzca nombre para continuar ')
    }
}

nombreJugador();


let randomNumber = () => {
    let num1 = 1;
    let num2 = 100;
    let numberRandom;
    let seguir;
    let encontrado;
    do {

        seguir = confirm('Desea pasar al siguiente turno?')
        if (seguir == true) {
            numberRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2);
            for (let i = 0; i < bingoCard.length; i++) {
                if (bingoCard[i].number === numberRandom) {
                    bingoCard[i].matched = true;
                    bingoCard[i].number = 'x';
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                 } else {
                     encontrado = false;
                }
            }
            if(encontrado){
                console.log("Se ha encontrado el numero: " + numberRandom);
                console.table(bingoCard);
            } 
            else{
                console.log('El numero: ' + numberRandom + ' no hay coincidencias');
            }
        }

    } while (seguir == true);
};

randomNumber();
```

Comment: Considera explicar tu aporte por favor